# In Tomcat 8 server.xml config file, is there a way dynamically configure a path to a resource using variable substitution?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets, tomcat8

I am using Apache Tomcat 8.

In `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml`, I have a `Resource` within the `GlobalNamingResources` tag:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myderby"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username=""
          password=""
          driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
          url="jdbc:derby:myderby;create=true"/>
```

But I would like to use my webapp context path as the base path to my database in the `url` parameter. For example:

```
url="jdbc:derby:${WEBAPP_HOME}/WEB-INF/db/myderby;create=true"
```

Is this possible and if so, what is the property I would need to set for `${WEBAPP_HOME}`?

Answer (score 4):

From the Tomcat 8 [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/):

> Tomcat configuration files are formatted as schemaless XML; elements and attributes are case-sensitive. **Apache Ant-style variable substitution is supported**; a system property with the name propname may be used in a configuration file using the syntax ${propname}. All system properties are available including those set **using the -D syntax**, those automatically made available by the JVM and those **configured in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties** file.

Therefore using a variable like ${WEBAPP_HOME} is possible.
conf/catalina.properties seems to be a good place to set it.
Or you could express the path to the derby database using the already defined variable ${catalina.base}:

`<Resource ... url="jdbc:derby:${catalina.base}/webapps/mycontext/WEB-INF/db/myderby;create=true"/>`

Comment: in case others were not aware of this excellent feature (like me until recently):
This features has actually been available since Tomcat 3.3.1 https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/serverxml.html
These days, with so many Tomcat deployments on same bare metal or virtual machines, this is an extremely handy feature to have!